# Offscreen laughter tracklaying in comedy show

Tags: sitcom, laughter, sound-editing

Hello everyone!
Recently we've shot a pilot of a sitcom.

I've never done something like this, and now at post im struggling at laying laughter regions, it just eats so much time!!

Here's how i do it: i audition various samples that i have, then i grab parts which i liked the most and edit them to fit the picture. Overall, i'm pleased with the result, but man, this way it eats time!

Does someone has an idea of doing it better, more time-efficient way? I'd be most grateful for any tips on this matter.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I've recently had to do the very same thing for a kids show I work on.  The most time efficient way to do this is load the laughs into a sampler, and 'play' them to picture.  My sampler of choice for this is Structure.  I map out my laughs in intensity from small to large across the keys leaving the black keys for any special laughs or reactions.  I've been using this approach for the last two seasons (around 35 episodes so far) and while it took a while to set up it has really made things easy.  I can play multiple keys to vary the intensity of the laughs and I've also made the samples velocity sensitive so I can have a further level of variance.

Answer (score 1):

How about a sampler?  If there is something I know I will need a lot of, I create a very basic Kontakt patch. I have done this for BG sessions.  Say for an interior suburb scene, I will put things like car bys, individual dog barks, children laughing...etc. This can be lame if you just use the same set of sounds on EVERYTHING you work on. But the sampler comes together fast enough that I build a new one for every film.

This allows for super quick auditioning you can perform to picture.  May still require some editing, but this has worked for me.

Chris

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I thought about making a patch for a kontakt, but i'm not really well familiar with it, could take some time for me to figure out an efficient way to use it.

Comment: Anton, If you are just triggering samples and not doing crazy scripting, Kontakt is pretty easy.  maybe 20 minutes of starter videos will get you up and running with this.  I have been using Miniminer to create the edited samples so they are pretty close before I load them in. Then it a simple drag and drop into Kontakt. 

You could take it much much further, but for something like this would get you started. 